# build:web fails inside npm script with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, npm, expo

We are using the expo-cli as a local dependency to run build:web from a npm script without global installation of expo-cli. When executing `npm run build:web` we get the exception below.

To create a minimal example we created a blank typescript project with expo init and ran `npm install expo-cli -D`. Doing the same without typescript everything worked as expected, so we think that the problem has something to do with typescript.

The following exception happens when trying to build:

```
>>npm run build:web

> @ build:web /home/anna/examplets
> expo build:web

(node:24316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anna/examplets/node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/src/withWorkbox.ts:142:10)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/anna/examplets/node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/webpack/withWorkbox.js:4:58)
(node:24316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24316) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Output of `expo-diagnostics`:

```
Expo CLI 3.4.1 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
      Shell: 4.4.20 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.16.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.2/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.2/bin/npm
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203
    npmPackages:
      @types/react: ^16.8.23 => 16.9.11 
      @types/react-native: ^0.57.65 => 0.57.65 
      expo: ^35.0.0 => 35.0.0 
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz => 0.59.8
```

This is the `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "build:web": "expo build:web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.65",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0",
    "expo-cli": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I posted the same question in the expo forum: https://forums.expo.io/t/build-web-fails-inside-npm-script-with-typescript/29444

Comment: This might be helpful: [withWorkbox.ts](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/blob/c82248438885f4fe494d5cfc72e2beaa62c2baaa/packages/webpack-config/src/withWorkbox.ts). As you can see the error happens at line number 142. It seems it can't load `register-service-worker.js` or something. Don't have the time at this moment but hope it helps!

Comment: @JKL There is not node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/src/withWorkbox.ts, but there is a node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/webpack/withWorkbox.ts, which is mentioned two lines below. I have no clue why. Why do you think it tried to load `register-service-worker.js` here?

Comment: Had this problem too, for now I've patched this line node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/webpack/withWorkbox.js:93 to
`if (false && entries.app && !entries.app.includes(swPath) && autoRegister) {` to skip the whole `register-service-worker.js` block

Comment: I had this error too and made a comment on the issue: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1161

"Not using TS or expo-cli as a dep myself, but readFile -> readFileSync fixed it for me."

Answer (score -3):

Add webpack-config to your project

`yarn add -D @expo/webpack-config`

Create a webpack.config.js file to the route of your project with:

```
const createExpoWebpackConfig = require("@expo/webpack-config");
module.exports = function(env, argv) {
  env.mode = "development";
  const config = createExpoWebpackConfig(env, argv);
  return config;
};
```

source: https://medium.com/@toastui/from-zero-to-publish-expo-web-react-native-for-web-tutorial-e3e020d6d3ff